# Android custom listview - change background and text color of selected item is not working?

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I am making custom listview with different background and text color. I have overridden setSelected(int position) method from my custom adaptor. its is working Fine in 7 inch tabs but not working in Samsung Galaxy Note Tablet (10.1 inch).

```
if(selectedPosition == position){
          ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderName)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
          ((LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderLayout)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.folders_list_bg_s);
      }else{
          ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderName)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
          ((LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderLayout)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.folders_list_bg);
      }
```

And the setselection method as

```
public void setSelected(int position) {
    selectedPosition = position;
}
```

Comment: first of all: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to highlight your list item with the specific way when it gets focus or when it is clicked?

Comment: This setSelected is working in all devices except 10 inch tab. Onselection of listview i am changing the background and textcolors of selected item.

Comment: As far as I can see, the stated problem (twice) is "not working", which is not nearly enough to prevent this being put on hold. If you can edit this to explain what the problem was _specifically_, that would help a great deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying the adapter we need to notify with notifyDatasetChanged() like

```
if(selectedPosition == position){
      ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderName)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      ((LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderLayout)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.folders_list_bg_s);
      notifyDatasetChanged();
  }else{
      ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderName)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
      ((LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folderLayout)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.folders_list_bg);
  }
```